# Mail not send in contact form using codeigniter and godaddy linux server

Tags: codeigniter

I designed http://gmgroups.co/ website using codeigniter. In this website    contact form mailing function is not working. I am using godaddy linux server.. I  ask to the customer care in godaddy they cant solve my problem.. They keep my call on hold only.. I try to solve this issue more then two day but i cant solve this problem.. Can any one pls help me to solve this issue.

This is my codeing

```
public function contactform(){
             //get the form data
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $from_email = $this->input->post('email');
            $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
            $message = $this->input->post('msg');

            //set to_email id to which you want to receive mails
            $to_email = 'info@gmgroups.co';

            //configure email settings
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_user'] = 'info@gmgroups.co';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxx';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtpout.secureserver.net';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '25';
            $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = '50';
            $config['newline'] = "\r\n"; //use double quotes
            $this->load->library('email', $config);
            $this->email->initialize($config);                        

            //send mail
            $this->email->from($from_email, $name);
            $this->email->to($to_email);
            $this->email->subject($subject);
            $this->email->message($message);
            if ($this->email->send())
            {
                // mail sent
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Thanks For Contacting Us! We Will Contact You                Very Soon..</div>');
            $this->load->view('layouts/head');  
            $this->load->view('contact');
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
            }
            else
            {
                //error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">There is error in sending mail! Please try again later</div>');
                 $this->load->view('layouts/head'); 
            $this->load->view('contact');
            $this->load->view('layouts/footer');
            }
```

Comment: replace ```$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';``` code with this ```$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';``` and then try.

Comment: I think you are trying to send email from USER_EMAIL to your email. You are taking from_email from user. Is it right?

Comment: @thank you kishor I change as ur comment now its working... Thank you...

Comment: then upvote the comments.

Comment: The tick symbol is not showing for ur comment...

Comment: I will update it as answer, the you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is not with your code but with GoDaddy who *appear* to require a mail relay - i.e. you can't connect to your server on port 25. You have to use their own mail server instead.

I don't have experience of GoDaddy but the following website (a few years old now) might well help: http://nickberardi.com/how-to-send-smtp-email-through-godaddy/

Your solution to rule this out would be to try mailing from the command line (I've not used this but something like http://www.binarytides.com/linux-mailx-command/) and see if you can email from the command line. If you can then its a PHP/Codeigniter issue - if not then its your provider.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';` code with this `$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';` and then try.

I think you are trying to send email from USER_EMAIL to your email. You are taking from_email from user. Is it right?